# How to pass the arguments from one keyword to another keyword in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
    I am generating the random username and password to create a new user. Then after execution, I need to delete the created user. 
${randomMerchantName} should be passed from one keyword to another keyword. But the value is not getting passed. Could anyone help me on this.
        Note: used some user defined keyword for generating random username and number.

        ***** Test Cases *****
        create merchant
            Given creating the merchant
            Then delete merchant

        ***** Keywords *****
        creating the merchant
                [Arguments]    ${randomMerchantName}
                ${random_number}     generate random number
                set suite variable    ${random_number}
                fill text    ${new_MerchantId}      ${random_number}
                ${randomMerchantName}    generate random name    ${8}
                set suite variable    ${randomMerchantName}
                fill text   ${new_MerchantName}     ${randomMerchantName}
                fill text    ${orgNumber}       23421
                click    ${new_merchantAddButton}
                click    ${PopUp_Okbutton}
                [Return]    ${randomMerchantName}

        delete merchant
                click   ${Agreement_titlecontainer}
                click    ${back_button}
                sleep    10s
                fill text    ${MerchantName}    ${randomMerchantName}
                click    ${merchant_SearchIcon}
                click    ${Merchant_deleteIcon}
                get text    ${merchant_delete_confirmationPopUp}     *=     {merchant_delete_PopUpmessage}
                click    ${PopUp_Okbutton}
                click    ${PopUp_Okbutton}
```

Automating Scenario: Creating the user then saving the userid as randomMerchantName then passing the value to delete the merchant.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NGzk.png)

Comment: Have you checked if there is a value to begin with after using the ``set suite variable``? You may want to simplify your example so people can try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the keyword 'set suite variable' is:

```
Set Suite Variable    ${var}    value
```

In your case this should do the job:

```
${tempRandomMerchantName}    generate random name    ${8}
Set Suite Variable    ${randomMerchantName}    ${tempRandomMerchantName}
```

You should now be able to use ${randomMerchantName} in 'delete merchant' keyword.